# Starting thread of its own class method is forbidden by ISO?

Tags: c++, multithreading

why defining:

```
void aClass::start(){
    void *ptr = this->startService;
    thread serviceth(ptr,this);
}
```

is forbidden by ISO? 
even if I:

```
void aClass::start(){
    thread serviceth(startService,this);
}
```

I got a error: "no matching function for call".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide `std::thread` with a function pointer like

```
void aClass::start(){
    thread serviceth(&aClass::startService, this);
}
```

in order to create a thread.  However we run into another issue with this.  Right after the thread is created the function ends and the thread is destroyed.  Since the thread is in a joinable state(`join()` or `detach()` was never called) the destructor of the thread will throw an exception.

You could make `serviceth` a member of `aClass` so that the thread can run while the class exist.

Comment: even that way it gives me errors. i will show tomorrow when I have access to the code.

Comment: terminate called without an active exception :/

Comment: Calling detach works. hey, and how can I pass a object to the function as a parameter? `thread w(&aClass::waitThis,this,cc);` where `cc` is an object?

Comment: @int3 Is `cc` and object of a type that `aClass::waitThis` takes as a parameter?